# How to add string containing array in NSMutable Array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray

I have this json

```
{
    "title": "xyz",
    "category": "Monetary",
    "target": "55",
    "achieve": "0",
    "todolist": [
        {
            "todoitem": "one"
        },
        {
            "todoitem": "two"
        },
        {
            "todoitem": "three"
        }
    ]
}
```

coming from API and I want to add todolist array to

In .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *todolist;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *todolists;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listnumber;
```

In .m file

```
todolist=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
todolists=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
listnumber=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
```

In function getting json

```
    todolists = [result valueForKey:@"todolist"];
             for (int j =0; j < todolist.count; j++)
             {
                 [todolist addObject:[[todolists objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"todoitem"]];
                 [listnumber addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j]];
             }

             [tvToDoList reloadData];
```

CellForRowAtIndexPath I am adding values two field

```
            static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
            TodolistTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            if(cell==nil)
            {
                cell = [[TodolistTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            }

            int row = (int)[indexPath row];

            cell.valListitem.text  = todolist[row];
            cell.lblNo.text = listnumber[row];


            return cell;
        }
```

where result is containing the whole json

Comment: What's the problem? What have you tried? Where is the error?

Comment: do you think its a right way to do this ?

Comment: This site is not for code review.

Comment: @VarunNaharia Assign listNumber as a NSArray. and You can then easily create mutable array from it.

Comment: there is no error but list dose not load in table view  and I am not asking you to review my code

Comment: @VarunNaharia: do you want 'one', 'two', 'three' in your array from JSON response ?

Comment: Please post your table method code too.

Comment: Can you show the code "Which is used to show in tableview"

Comment: You have a dictionary, under the key "todolist" it has an array, and each array element is a dictionary with a key "todoitem". Do you have a problem writing the trivial ten lines of code that are needed to extract the values "one", "two" and "three"?

Comment: problem solved thanks to Prashant Tukadiya and Pradip Vanparia

Answer (score 4):

Try this in one line code.

```
todolist = [[[result valueForKey:@"todolist"] valueForKey:@"todoitem"] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Good Logic. Good answer.

Comment: you didn't add `addObject` app is crash

Comment: but +1 for your `mutableCopy`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get string from array here is solution

```
for (int i =0; i < listnumber.count; i++) 
{
  [todolist addObject:[[listnumber objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"todoitem"]];
}
```

Comment: not working and there is some warning ` Ordered comparison between pointer and interger('int' and 'NSMutableArray *')`  and its an infinity loop

Comment: sorry i made some mistake there just update  in for loop  `i < listnumber.count`  where  `i<listnumber`

Comment: app crash by this `[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff131ee8dc0`

Comment: make sure you get data in array format in listnumber  just put debug point there and in for loop and let me know where it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Parse your json string and get the todos as **NSArray** from that.

@Try this

```
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error = nil;
    id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data
                      options:0
                      error:&error];

   NSArray *todos = [object valueForKey:@"todolist"];

  NSMutableArray *mutableToDos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:todos];
```

Here is the code for display in cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   NSDictionary *todo = [mutableToDos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [[cell textLabel] setText:[todo valueForKey:@"todoitem"];

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: did you check with debugger the array contains the value or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *todolist;
todolist=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

//Convert to NSData
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//JSON object
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

//Array of ToDo List
NSArray *list = (NSArray *)[object valueForKey:@"todolist"];

//Fetch items of ToDo List
for (int i =0; i < [list count]; i++) 
{
  [todolist addObject:[[list objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"todoitem"]];
}

NSLog(@"Array :: %@", todolist);
```

Hopefully, this will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: simply parse the json string and use it